# Socket already in use broadcast

Tags: c#, broadcast

I want do Broadcast chat console application on C#, created listen task, and send in while true messages.
But when i tried run second user i have error that socket already use port. How this fix? and what i do not correctly? Screenshot error -> [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L2pe.jpg)

```
private static int localPort = 15000;
private static string nickName;
private static string msg;
private static string datasend;
private static string fullmsg;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Nickname:");
        nickName = Console.ReadLine();
        Thread tRec = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receiver));
        tRec.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            msg = Console.ReadLine();
            datasend = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            fullmsg = datasend + ":" + nickName + "-" + msg;
            Send(fullmsg);
        }
    }
}

private static void Send(string datagram)
{
    UdpClient sender = new UdpClient();
    sender.EnableBroadcast = true;
    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, localPort);
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(datagram);
        sender.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, endPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString() + "\n  " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sender.Close();
    }
}

public static void Receiver()
{
    UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(localPort);
    receivingUdpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, localPort);
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n-----------*******Chat*******-----------");
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            string returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes);
            Console.WriteLine(" --> " + returnData.ToString());
        }
}
```

Comment: You should be using only one socket for both send and receive.  You can have only one sockets with same Source IP, Destination IP, and port number.  You have using the same three parameter for both the send and receive socket causing a dupliction and creating the error.

Comment: @jdweng and how this do?

Comment: See msdn example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=net-5.0.  You may need to register for a group if the port is being used by another application.

Comment: It's true that sockets are bidirectional/"full-duplex", but that doesn't seem to be the issue you're asking about. Rather you have a problem running more than one instance of the process on the same PC. This is because the local UDP port is already in use when you start the second process. You should not attempt this; only one process on a given network adapter should be listening/receiving on a given port. Your second process should catch the `IOException` and not attempt to listen to broadcasts. If you really want two or more processes on the same machine to receive the same ...

Comment: ... datagrams, you should use UDP **multicast**, which is a related but different technique. Each process will join a single multicast group (channel) and can all receive datagrams using that same group. You could use `SO_REUSEADDR` to have the processes share the broadcast port locally, but that is likely to cause much more serious problems than what you have now. I strongly recommend against that. See duplicate for more details.